# dynamically adding element with increment in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.addquestions = function(){
    $scope.count++;
    var newEl = $compile('<selectbox-dir count="{{count}}" change="cng()"></selectbox-dir>')($scope);   

    angular.element(document.getElementById('content')).append(newEl);

}
```

I am trying to get index of every appended element in container, Need help to solve this issue. Please have a look on this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/QxTYcaQReUeCjkKfyEIB?p=preview

Comment: you should not use `angular.element` in controller instead in directive

Comment: I want append same element "newE1" from many other controller events and also from few directives. what is the best practice to make that element as global? should we create service of it and inject it to controller and directives?

Comment: i not sure what you mean _same element "newE1"_, now you create _new_ "newEl" on every button click. Can you explain with sample what you try to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change ...

```
$compile('<selectbox-dir count="{{count}}" change="cng()"></selectbox-dir>')($scope);
```

... to ...

```
$compile('<selectbox-dir count="' + $scope.count + '" change="cng()"></selectbox-dir>')($scope);
```

You track the value on scope, but want to display the value at the time the function executes, not the changed scope value.

Same change here, but a bit easier to see ...

```
count="' + $scope.count + '"
```

Comment: I want append same element "newE1" from many other controller events and also from few directives. what is the best practice to make that element as global? should we create service of it and inject it to controller and directives?